# Exception is not thrown even though conditions are met

Tags: java, exception

I am building a lexer for a simple programming language, that takes a string as input and returns a list of Tokens, e.g. 'def' will become T_Def(). I have no problem with the functionality other than LexicalException is not thrown when a string that is not in the language comes up.

```
interface Lexer {

    public List<Token> lex(String input)
            throws LexicalException, Task1Exception;
}

class MyLexer implements Lexer {

    String keyWordRegex = "def|if|then|do|else|while|skip|repeat|continue|break|until";
    String binOpRegex = "\\+|\\-|\\/|\\*";
    String conidtionalRegex = "={1,2}|<|>|<=|>=";
    String miscRegex = ",|\\)|\\(|\\}|\\{|:=|;";
    String intRegex = "\\b(\\d+)\\b";
    String idenRegex = "\\b([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\\b";

    ArrayList<Token> tk = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Token> lex(String input) throws LexicalException {
        try {
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(keyWordRegex + "|" + binOpRegex + "|"
                    + conidtionalRegex + "|" + miscRegex + "|" + intRegex + "|" + idenRegex);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
            while (m.find()) {
                switch (m.group(0)) {

                    // Keyword cases
                    
                    // Binary Operator cases                 
                    
                    // Conditional cases
                    
                    // Miscellaneous cases
                    
                    // Identifier and Integer
                    default:

                        if (m.group(0).matches(intRegex)) {
                            tk.add(new T_Integer(Integer.parseInt(m.group(0))));
                            System.out.println("int");
                        }
                        if (m.group(0).matches(idenRegex)) {
                            tk.add(new T_Identifier(m.group(0)));
                            System.out.println("iden");
                        }
                        if (!(m.group(0).matches(idenRegex)) && !(m.group(0).matches(intRegex))) {
                            System.out.println("error"); //print wouldn't be in final
                            throw new LexicalException(m.group(0));
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

        } catch (LexicalException e) {
            System.out.println(e.msg + " is not in the language.");
        }
        return tk;
    }
}

class Task1 {

    public static MyLexer create() throws Task1Exception {

        return new MyLexer();
    }
}
```

When my input string is :

```
    def (x) { && },
```

my output is:

```
    [T_Def@7852e922, T_LeftBracket@4e25154f, T_Identifier@70dea4e,T_RightBracket@5c647e05, T_LeftCurlyBracket@33909752, T_RightCurlyBracket@55f96302].
```

This output is right but an exception should have been thrown and a message printed saying '&& is not in the language'.

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't happening? Is my if statement wrong?

Comment: A `find()` loop will ***find*** any matching text, skipping over text that doesn't match. E.g. `"a + b"` will find `"a"`, `"+"`, and `"b"`, skipping over the spaces, and `"a && b"` will find `"a"` and `"b"`, skipping over `" && "`. Your code never sees the `&&`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your response, do you have any suggestions for what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make the regex also match any unexpected text, excluding white-space.

We also need to fix a few things:

- `-` and `/` are not special characters in a Java regex, so no need to escape them.
- A `[ ]` character class is faster than using `|` OR pattern, e.g. use `[-+/*]` instead of `\+|-|/|\*`.
- The `|` OR pattern searches in the listed order, so make sure a match is not a prefix of a later match. E.g. `<|<=` will match `<`, not `<=`, so it should be `<=|<`. Even better to use optional matching, i.e. `<=?`.

Since you need to know which category actually matched, use capture groups and check which one did the match. That way we don't have to re-execute each category regex's.

```java
String keyWordRegex = "def|if|then|do|else|while|skip|repeat|continue|break|until";
String binOpRegex = "[-+/*]"; // '-' must be first or last
String condRegex  = "={1,2}|[<>]=?"; // =, ==, <, <=, >, >=
String miscRegex  = "[,;(){}]|:=";
String intRegex   = "\\b[0-9]+\\b";
String idenRegex  = "\\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\\b";
String otherRegex = "(?U:\\S)"; // match any other single non-space (invalid) character
```

```java
public ArrayList<Token> lex(String input) throws LexicalException {
    ArrayList<Token> tk = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(" + keyWordRegex + ")" + // Group 1
                                   "|(" + binOpRegex + ")" +   // Group 2
                                   "|(" + condRegex + ")" +    // Group 3
                                   "|(" + miscRegex + ")" +    // Group 4
                                   "|(" + intRegex + ")" +     // Group 5
                                   "|(" + idenRegex + ")" +    // Group 6
                                   "|(" + otherRegex + ")");   // Group 7
        for (Matcher m = r.matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
            String token = m.group();
            if (m.start(1) != -1) { // Keyword cases
                // code here
            } else if (m.start(2) != -1) { // Binary Operator cases
                // code here
            } else if (m.start(3) != -1) { // Conditional cases
                // code here
            } else if (m.start(4) != -1) { // Miscellaneous cases
                // code here
            } else if (m.start(5) != -1) { // Integer cases
                tk.add(new T_Integer(Integer.parseInt(token)));
                System.out.println("int");
            } else if (m.start(6) != -1) { // Identifier cases
                tk.add(new T_Identifier(token));
                System.out.println("iden");
            } else { // Other (invalid) cases
                System.out.println("error"); //print wouldn't be in final
                throw new LexicalException(token);
            }
        }
    } catch (LexicalException e) {
        System.out.println(e.msg + " is not in the language.");
        throw e;
    }
    return tk;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly and looks amazing.